# How to apply small caps to a font family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is it possible to apply small caps to a font family instead of a tag? I am using the orator font (which is a small caps monospaced font) but I realise its not really web safe. Andale looks similar and is web safe but isn't a small caps font. So in the absence of orator I would like Andale to be called on with small caps without adding the small caps attribute to the orator. For the H1 tag. How can I do this?

Comment: There are no web safe fonts. The “small caps” you get in almost all cases are fake small caps (reduced-size capital letters). It is unclear what is being asked here; in particular the title is in conflict with the question body.

Comment: Tried to keep it short so sorry for the confusion. I would like to mimic the small caps style that my default font (orator) has if the user does not have Orator installed. So I wanted to know if there was a way of adding the "font variant: small caps" tag to H1 without it affecting my default font because it is small caps by default.

Answer (score 4):

Apply `font-variant: small-caps` to your H1 tag.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qhcz/)

Comment: That will make orator small caps to which I don't want. Orator is in the H1 tag too.

Comment: Whatever “to apply small caps to a font family instead of a tag” might mean, it surely does not mean *this*.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What other definition of small caps is there?

Comment: Well, there is the typographic definition of small caps, which is very different from the implementations of `font-variant: small-caps`, but that’s not the point. The point is that the answer suggest applying a CSS declaration to a “tag” (apparently meaning an element), but the question explicitly said “to a font family instead of a tag”.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a different (more thinner) font and then use the :first-letter CSS3 selector to make the first letter larger instead. There are a number of Open-Type fonts similar to the one you posted.

```
table.form td {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 15px;
}

table.form td:first-letter {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Or Another way  :

[image]

Comment: And then what if not only the first letter must be larger, such as in most English titles. I'm sorry but this is not (and was not back in 2014) in any practical way a solution to the problem, merely to a very narrow subset of it.